# CQRS, EventStore and event sourcing: concurrency exceptions in SaveEvents use RPC?

Tags: rabbitmq, rpc, cqrs, event-sourcing

I am implementing an event store. I have defined a SaveEventsConsumer that handles the storage of events in the event store. If I understand correctly CQRS commands should have no response. Nevertheless, there can be concurrency problems when saving events to the event store. I use RabbitMQ. Should the client be notified so it can notify the user for example? How should it be implemented? Using RPC and an error format?

My first approach is:

> Client use RPC like style. SaveEventsConsumer notifies the client (success or failure). If an failure occurs (e.g. concurrency) return the exception to the client.

Is this solution aligned to the CQRS pattern? Is a good approach? Is there any other approach? Is there any improvement? Should I use any AMQP header or property to indicate the error (mimicking HTTP error codes)?

---

Example, in a cluster:

Two instances of the same application modify the same aggregate. These intances should coordinate (externally to the event-store) or is the event-store which has to detect and notify the response?

Comment: What concurrency issue are you expecting? Eg 2 commands from difference users try to cancel the same order - In this case there's no point in throwing a concurrency error since the end result is the same.

Comment: For example, two instances of the same application modify the same aggregate. These intances should coordinate (externally to the event-store) or is the event-store which has to detect and notify the response?

Comment: perhaps this will help https://geteventstore.com/blog/20130220/getting-started-part-2-implementing-the-commondomain-repository-interface/ and this https://github.com/EventStore/EventStore/wiki/Optimistic-Concurrency-&-Idempotence

Comment: based on this Greg's EventStore if the wrong version is given then a Wrong Version exception is given

Comment: but personally i still think you should be intelligent about what commands are rejected  - eg a rename-item command should be allowed to succeed regardless of version ie to fix a typo

Answer (score 2):

While it is true you don't return values from a command, an exception can still occur. A concurrency exception is one example. This implies the exception is thrown as part of the processing of a command. This makes sense when you think about it. You don't ever want events published which have not yet been committed to the event store. It follows then that concurrency conflict checking needs to happen as part of the overall command process.

I have a post which may help. You can find it [here](http://danielwhittaker.me/2014/09/29/handling-concurrency-issues-cqrs-event-sourced-system/).

Comment: Thank you. To return the exception to the client, What should be used in rabbitmq? RPC?